# Why define functions with the empty domain? (specifically in primitive recursion)

Tags: functions, computability

A function can have an empty domain, as long as the range is not empty, as this satisfies the conditions of existence and uniqueness of images. However such a function can never be called, as there is no value in the empty set to pass to it.
Primitive recursion defines some functions to be $\mathbb{N}_0^k \to \mathbb{N}_0$ with $k \in \mathbb{N}_0$. Thus it defines a function $\emptyset \to \mathbb{N}$. But what for? That function is impossible to ever call. What is the rational behind defining such uncallable functions?

Comment: A function with an empty domain will have an empty range.

Comment: What value of $k$ gives $\Bbb N_0^k=\emptyset$?

Comment: 0 does, does it not?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: Then what is $M^0$ for any set $M$?

Comment: Since $M^k$ is defined as the set of tuples of length $k$ whose entries are all in $M$, you find, by setting $k=0$, that $M^0$ is the set of tuples of length $0$ whose entries are all in $M$. There's exactly one such tuple, namely $\langle\rangle$. So $M^0$ is the set consisting of this one element, $M^0=\{\langle\rangle\}$ (no matter what $M$ is).

Comment: The question sounds as if you think the only thing one can do with a function is to call it, by applying it to some element in its domain.  There are lots of other things one can do with a function.  Probably most relevant to your question is that one can use a function as an ingredient in the definition of other functions (with different domains).  Another possibility is that the function under consideration might be passed as an input to some other (higher order) function.